# Sequence of circumferences

Tags: geometry

"Be a circumference of radius $R$ and center $O$. A second circumference is drawed in such a way that is tangent to the first circumference (in a point $P$) and goes through the center of the first circumference; a third circumference is drawed in such a way that is tangent to the second circumference, in the point $O$, and goes through the center of the second circumference and so on (that is, the $(n+1)-$circumference is tangent to the $n-$circumference in the center of the $(n-1)-$circumference and goes through the center of the $n-$circumference. Find the distance between the center of the $n$-th circumference and the point $P$".

I made  a aproximate drawing if its not clear enough with that description:

[image]

**My try**

I saw that, the radiuses of the circumferences goes like : $$R, \frac{R}{2}, \frac{R}{4}, \frac{R}{8},\frac{R}{16},...,\frac{R}{2^n}$$

So the distance between the Point P and the center of the $n-$circumference will be:

$$\frac{R}{2} + \frac{R}{4} + \frac{R}{8} + \frac{R}{16}+ ... +\frac{R}{2^n}$$

This is equivalent to: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {R}{2^n}=R \times \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {1}{2^n}$$

But i don't know if my answer is correct or not. Any help and corrections will be apreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radii of the circles are correct. However, the summation is wrong. Work through it step by step. If d(n) is the distance of center of the nth circle from P, you get:

d(1) = R

d(2) = R - (R/2)

d(3) = R - (R/2) + (R/4)

Thus, you get d(n) = $R \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\frac{-1}{2})^k$

You can sum the geometric sequence to get: $\frac{2R}{3} (1-(\frac{-1}{2})^{n})$ for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: But if i'm not wrong, $R-\frac{R}{2}=R/2$, and the same happen with  $R-\frac{R}{2}+\frac{R}{4}=R/4$. So will be the same that my sum. Sorry if i'm wrong.

Comment: R - R/2 + R/4 = 3R/4 not R/4. Look at your figure at the center of the 3rd circle. It's distance from P is 3R/4 not R/4. And if you go further it becomes more clear. Distance of center of 4th circle from P is R - R/2 + R/4 - R/8 = 5R/8 etc. However, in your sum R/2 + R/4 + R/8 = 7R/8.